# How to read data from azure storage table using azure ad authentication?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-table-storage

I want to read data from Azure storage table which is locally working fine as I have registered my IP into firewall settings of azure storage but when I published the same into azure I'm getting forbidden error, maybe due to authorization. How can I read data from storage table?

I tried something like this.

```
            new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
                "AccountName", "AccountKey"), true);

expected response should get all the data from azure storage table after publishing it into azure. but now getting forbidden error.
```

Comment: Try to choose the option https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dn7J.png and try again.

Comment: @joy already tried but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure web app is not a [trusted Microsoft Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#exceptions). \

There might be 2 optional solutions:

1. If your web app and storage account are in different data centers, you can add all the app's outbound IPs to white list. You can find the outbound IPs in the web app's properties:

[image]

2. You can use [App Service Environments (ASE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro). With ASE, your web app will be isolated. It will be protected within a virtual network. In this way, you can allow access from that virtual network in storage firwall.

Comment: Navigate to your function app resource,  Click on   "Platform features"  -> "properties". And you will see the outbound IPs for function IP. Please note that this only works when your app and storage are in different data centers.

Comment: Is there any other way to do?

Comment: You can use App Service Environments (ASE).

Comment: is there any other way without ASE as i cant create ASE due to permission.